# how can i end a certain condition in python?

Tags: python

How can I exit if a certain condition is met? The input in the loop is still popping up after I wrote the correct answer.

I've tried using `exit()`, `break`, `system.exit`, `system.quit`

```
x = int(input("write a number : "))
y = int(input("write another number : "))
result = x * y
guess = int(input(str(x) + " is multiplied to "+ str(y) + " is equals to? \n " ))
if guess == result:
    print("congrats")
    ### if this condition is met i want to end here
guess1 = 0
while guess1 != result:
    guess1 = int(input("write another answer : "))
    if guess1 == result:
        print("this time you got it")
```

I want to get rid of the other input if the other condition is met.

Comment: format text - it is unreadable  - remove ###

Comment: where did you use `exit()`, `break`, `system.exit()` (it has to be with `()`) and `system.quit()` (it has to be with `()`) ? Did you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can always use "`else:`" to skip some part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an else statement after the if block. It will either stop the code if the condition is met or it will continue to the else part of the code.

```
if guess == result:
    print("congrats")
    ### if this condition is met it will print congrats and stop
else:
    guess1 = 0
    while guess1 != result:
        guess1 = int(input("write another answer : "))
        if guess1 == result:
            print("this time you got it")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set result to 0 if the condition is met.

```py
x = int(input("write a number : "))
y = int(input("write another number : "))
result = x * y
guess = int(input(str(x) + " is multiplied to "+ str(y) + " is equals to? \n " ))
if guess == result:
    print("congrats")
    result = 0  # if the condition is met, the while loop would never run if the result is the same as guess1
guess1 = 0
while guess1 != result:
    guess1 = int(input("write another answer : "))
    if guess1 == result:
        print("this time you got it")

###I want to get rid of the other input if the other condition is met
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Put that code inside of a function and use `return` when you want to terminate the whole thing.
2. Use `sys.exit(0)` at the point where you want to terminate. You'd need to import the sys module (`import sys`) for that.

On another note, you could just refactor your code and make it much cleaner by:

Setting the guess to None initially and then entering the loop. Your code will be:

```py
x = int(input("write a number : "))
y = int(input("write another number : "))
result = x * y
guess = None
while guess != result:
    guess = int(input("write another answer : "))
    if guess == result:
        print("congrats")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `else` to skip part of code

```
if guess == result:
    print("congrats")
else:
    guess1 = 0
    while guess1 != result:
       guess1 = int(input("write another answer : "))
       if guess1 == result:
           print("this time you got it")

# this line will be executed
```

Or `exit()` to exit script

```
if guess == result:
    print("congrats")
    ### if this condition is met i want to end here
    exit()

guess1 = 0
while guess1 != result:
    guess1 = int(input("write another answer : "))
    if guess1 == result:
        print("this time you got it")
```